# RESTEasy: getPathSegments().get(1);

Tags: resteasy

Can someone tell me what "PathSegment model = info.getPathSegments().get(1);" do, specifically, what does he getPathSegments().get(1) mean?  Please provide a sample URL for demonstration.  The book didn't give an example URL for this one.

Also, is there such a thing as get(0); ?

```
 @Path("/cars/{make}")
 public class CarResource 
 {
     @GET
     @Path("/{model}/{year}")
     @Produces("image/jpeg")
     public Jpeg getPicture(@Context UriInfo info) 
     {
         String make = info.getPathParameters().getFirst("make");
         PathSegment model = info.getPathSegments().get(1);
         String color = model.getMatrixParameters().getFirst("color");
        ...
     }
 }
```

Thanks again,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split the path of a URL by a '/' you'll get a list of path-segments. So e.g. the path `/cars/ford/mustang/1976` contains the four segments `[cars, ford, mustang, 1976]`. `info.getPathSegments().get(1)` should return the segment `ford`.

The [PathSegment](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/PathSegment.html) holds also the associated MatrixParameters of the current segment. MatrixParameters can be used if you want to filter the resources with a parameter that affects only one segment like here:

```
/cars/ford/mustang;generation=two/1976
```

Comment: Thanks.  Also, the book mentioned that "The getPath() methods allow you to obtain the relative path JAX-RS used to match
the incoming request."  Is your example a relative path?  If not, what is a relative path?  I mean, I can understand it if the book stated xyz is the root, and therefore whatever comes after is the relative path, but it didn't state it.  Thanks again.

Comment: A absolute path is the full path starting with the root slash. The absolute path of `www.stackoverflow.com/one/two/three` is `/one/two/three`. Relative means relative to a parent path. The path `two/three` relative to `www.stackoverflow.com/one` will result in the same resource. The path in the example above is relative to the value defined in `@ApplicationPath`.

Comment: I'll try to use a word I've recently learned "context" =)  Is @ApplicationPath the "context"?  Is context the application I compiled and installed onto a web server?  Let's say the name of the program is "one" then that is the root?  and two/three is relative to the parent path of "one"?  Let me know if I understand these words correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: The context-path (or context-root) is the first path segment after the domain. It can be obtained via [HttpServletRequest.getContextPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath()) and is often the name of your war-file. The `@ApplicationPath` is the next path segment. But if you use `/` as `@ApplicationPath` it's identical to the context-path.

Comment: Thanks Lefloh.  You have no idea how helpful it is for me to get the terminologies clear.  There's tutorials and book I've been reading which leaves me in a haze when these terminologies aren't explained in advance.  Thanks again.